# Google Script: how to display GmailApp.search - mail data

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I'm trying display starred mails in Logger.

```
function viewStarred() {
  Logger.log( GmailApp.search('is:starred') );
}
```

but result in my Logger is this:

> [GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, .... GmailThread]

how can I display mail subjects? or content...

Here is my screen:
[image: here is my logger screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is behaviour as expected. If you see the [documentation for GmailApp.search](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#search), you'll see that it returns an Array of GmailThread objects. 
Logger.log cannot print out a GmailThread array object directly

So, you have to 
a. Single out the GmailThread object you want to print
b. Print specific information about a GmailThread (subject, sender etc.)

See example below

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('is:starred');
for (var i in threads){
  Logger.log(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
}
```